# Cannot use Gear VR app with error message "com.samsung.android.hmt.vrsvc is not installed"

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-5, samsung-gear-vr

I have Samsung Galaxy S5 and Samsung Gear VR. I am trying to use [CB Enabler for Gear VR](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.youtopiavr.cbenabler), but I keep getting the message:

> com.samsung.android.hmt.vrsvc is not installed.

How can I install `com.samsung.android.hmt.vrsvc` and try to run the application again?

Answer (score 0):

Searching `com.samsung.android.hmt.vrsvc` reveals that it is *Gear VR Service* (from [list of S6 bloatware on XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s6/general/list-freezing-bloatware-samsung-s6-t3192919)).

Researching about Gear VR Service itself, it seems that Gear VR only supports a handful of devices *officially* (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Gear_VR)):

- Galaxy Note 4 (developer version)
- Galaxy Note 5
- Galaxy S6/S6 Edge/S6 Edge+
- or Galaxy S7/S7 Edge

And thus, those devices have Gear VR Service* installed.

You can still check if your device has this by going to **Setting - Application Manager - Gear VR Service**, and check if it's there, enabled/disabled.

[image]

<sup>Image courtesy of [Unreal Engine documentation](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Platforms/GearVR/Debugging/)</sup>

Regarding installing this service on other devices, I have searched and as of current writing, nothing came up. Most of them can only suggest to *wait until Samsung officially push the Gear VR Software update to your device*.

---

<sup>*may depend on update by carrier (from [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/GearVR/comments/3vlluu/gear_vr_not_working_with_note5_no_setup_wizard/)).</sup>

Comment: I know, right ? nothing came up to me either.I guess we are supposed to buy the other device if we want the service installed.

Comment: I have just sent a support request to samsung, I post the solution as soon as I get one, my question is not on the internet yet, so I will be the first one to solve this and possibly help others with the same question.

Comment: So, I contacted samsung and they said it is incompatible, I will keep trying to find a workaround and post the solution if there is one.